# Dynamics 365 CRM SDK or Rest API

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365

I need to create a CRM E-Mail activity with attachement from code. As far as I know there are two ways to do this. I could use the dynamics 365 CRM SDK or the dynamics 365 CRM Rest API. My question is which one I should use at the moment? I know Microsoft has many good API, but many of them seemed unfinished to me. Can you guys help me out?

Comment: What is the version of Dynamics you are targeting? While the Dynamics 365 CRM Api only supports version 9.0 and up

Comment: What platform/language are you developing on?

Comment: I am using C# .Net Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've you're in the .Net Framework, always use the SDK.  It hasn't really changed since 2011, and they are slowly porting the calls over from the SOAP endpoint to the WebApi for you, with no work on your end.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing integration from outside CRM, I would recommend WEB API which is the cross-platform RESTful solution going forward. Before 8.x CRM version - SDK was the only option available (still you can use it today).

The keywords are important, you can find lot of community blogs for code samples & better documentation. You can setup Postman & test the web api endpoints, even [you can use CRM REST Builder](https://www.wipfli.com/insights/articles/tc-crm-rest-builder-dynamics-crms-web-api) for development purpose.

**Endpoint**: `<your instance url>/api/data/v9.1/emails`

[Create Email with attachment using SDK](https://crmblocks.blogspot.com/2016/06/how-to-send-email-with-attachment-in.html)

[Create Email using web api](https://www.cloudfronts.com/creating-an-email-activity-in-ms-crm-through-webapi/)

[Adding attachments using web api](https://bettercrm.blog/2017/07/19/how-to-create-an-attachment-using-webapi-in-dynamics-365/)